# How to summon mobs with a different health value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been experimenting with custom mobs and I wanted to summon a mob with 16 health (8 hearts). I've been searching on the internet for a long time, but unsuccessfully. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `/summon EntityHorse {Health:1}` from [Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351954-how-to-give-mobs-custom-health-with-summon) replace `EntityHorse` with mob

Comment: No problem :) happy to help.

Comment: @Alex You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Skylinerw I did :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
`/summon EntityHorse {Health:1}`

It will spawn a horse with half a heart. Change `EntityHorse` with the mob you want.

[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351954-how-to-give-mobs-custom-health-with-summon)

Also try `/summon EntityHorse X Y Z {Health:1}`

Answer (score -3):

Give the mob this tag:

```
/summon MOB ~ ~ ~ {Health:10s}
```

i dont know why the 's' but it works!

Comment: Your just coping an already (basically) accepted answer

Comment: You are misrepresenting the datatype by using "s"; Health is no longer a short and is instead a float (declared as `Health:10f` or `Health:10.0f`). However, when creating new data (`/summon`, `/entitydata`, etc.), most numerical tags do not require having the correct datatype declared, so either will work, except you cannot have decimals in a short.